# How do I assign a value to a variable stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example:

```
var a = b = c = null;
var array = [a, b, c];
var value = 5;
```

How could I assign `value` to `a` using `array`, without having `array[0]` be overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I assign a value to a variable stored in an array?

You can't.

I think you have a misconception here: JavaScript is *pass-by-value*, i.e. the array **doesn't hold a reference to the variable**, it holds the **value** that the variable had at the moment the array was created.

When you write `[a, b, c]` it literally means *"evaluate `a`, `b` and `c` and add their values to the array"*. After the array was created, there is no knowledge anymore where the values came from.

This makes sense, since this is the same behavior if you use literals or other expressions instead of variables: `[1, 40 + 2, "foo"]`. It simply evaluates each expression and adds the result to the array.